# C++ Why does "istringstream" use parenthesis after the name?

Tags: c++

I was learning some C++, and I got to the part where I learn about converting from string and integers. I was looking at the code, and it said something like:

```
istringstream converter(stringVariable);
```

If "converter" is a variable name, then why do you use () after it?

Comment: How did you expect it to look?

Comment: That's not just `istringstream`, it's just about everything. It's called direct initialization.

Answer (score 6):

The parentheses enclose an argument to the [`istringstream` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream).

```
istringstream converter(stringVariable);
//                            ^^ variable being passed as argument to the
//                               istringstream constructor
```

This initialization syntax applies to all types with constructors which have parameters. This one of the standard C++ object initialization syntaxes, although beware: under certain circumstances, similar constructs can be parsed as function declarations, in what is known as [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). So this

```
istringstream mystream();
```

would be parsed as a function, eventhough `std::istringstream` has a constructor that accepts no parameters.

Comment: Oh, I thought that you'd have to say some thing like "istringstream converter = new istringstream(stringVariable);" Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AlexKillian no, that wouldn't compile, `new` returns a pointer. And C++ isn't java, you don't have to call new all the time :-)

Comment: @AlexKillian, In fact, you should barely ever use `new`, even less when `std::make_unique` arrives.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's the way you call constructor of `istringstream` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in today's version of C++ (C++11), it's better to write that as:

```
istringstream converter{stringVariable};
```

This is called "uniform initialization" syntax, it works much the same as the one with parentheses, but can never be mistaken for a function declaration (no "most vexing parse").